# Multiple parameterized updates with C# and Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm trying to execute multiple updates like this

```
UPDATE clients SET name = :name WHERE clientId = :clientID
```

I've tried something like this

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText =
    "begin " +
    "  UPDATE clients SET name = " + name1 + " WHERE clientId = " + clientId1 +
    "  UPDATE clients SET name = " + name2 + " WHERE clientId = " + clientId2 +
    "end;";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

but I need to execute hundreds of parameterized updates like the first one

Comment: Where is your problem? Use the parameterized update from the top. It is the purpose to execute it several times with different values.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If you are using ODP.NET, you can use [Array Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B14164_01/featOraCommand.htm#i1007888)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: multiples updates in one round trip to the database @BobJarvis

Comment: As mentioned above, use the parameterized update and Array Bindings to guarantee performance.